# What is the difference between import calls in Clojure?

Tags: function, import, clojure, difference

The following import statements in Clojure all seem to be valid:

```
(import '(com.example.db.modules DBModule))
(import 'com.example.db.modules.DBModule)
(import '[com.example.db.modules DBModule])
(import (com.example.db.modules DBModule))
(import com.example.db.modules.DBModule)
(import [com.example.db.modules DBModule])
```

But what is their difference, and why should I use one or the other? (Especially when importing several Classes in one import-statement)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `import` macro [removes the `quote` of each expression](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L3295) if there is one, so there's no difference between quoting the arguments it receives from not quoting them. This means the expressions `(import 'com.example.db.modules.DBModule))` and `(import com.example.db.modules.DBModule)` are equivalent. You can check this by macro-expanding each expression.

```
user=> (macroexpand-1 '(import 'com.example.db.modules.DBModule))
(do (clojure.core/import* "com.example.db.modules.DBModule"))
user=> (macroexpand-1 '(import com.example.db.modules.DBModule))
(do (clojure.core/import* "com.example.db.modules.DBModule"))
```

Specifying a vector or a list allows you to import more than one class from the same namespace, using either one is equivalent since `import` makes use of Clojure's sequence abstraction to `map` and `reduce` over them.

To sum up:

- Use `(import com.example.db.modules.DBModule)` when you need only a single class from a namespace.
- Use either `(import [com.example.db.modules DBModule])` or `(import (com.example.db.modules DBModule))` when you need to import more than one class. I personally prefer vectors.
- You can provide any combination of the previous items as arguments to `import`. For example `(import com.example.db.modules.DBModule [com.example.model Client Order Payment]))`.
- Don't quote the arguments since it is not necessary.